# How to count rows from SQL DB table in VB.NET WPF application?

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

I just want who many number of record comes against specific query, nothing else.
for example select count(column name) from table
answer = 15

```
  Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  qnumber," + item + " FROM tencmpC1", cc) 
            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            cmd.Connection.Open()


            Dim oleRdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            'txt1.Text = oleRdr.HasRows

                oleRdr.Read()
                Dim count As Integer
                While oleRdr.Read()
                    count = count + 1
                End While
                txt1.Text = count


            oleRdr.Close()
```

I try this code to get number of rows from query but failed to get. Please give me piece of code, anyone.

Comment: please answer this question if you understand know?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  qnumber," + item + " FROM tencmpC1", cc)
Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
cmd.Connection.Open()
Dim ds As new Data.Dataset 
Dim dt as new Data.DataTable
adp.Fill(ds)
dt=ds.Tables(0)
Dim count as Integer=dt.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Dear  mahadev error arises Cannot find table 0.
http://stackoverflow.com/users/1662394/mahadev

Comment: @WaqasAli If the answer doesn't answer your question, please don't accept it.