# How to count number of rows in a sql table with vb.net using sqlclient class

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table name
```

this above code work fine in standalone sql table, but who can I do this simple task with in vb.net wpf project ?

Comment: did u tried anything?

Comment: yes too much thing like grid.rows.count with loop

loop with data reader 
loop with data table

Comment: first you need to create a sql connection..then create sql command..then execute it..try and post your code..then we can help

Comment: '  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable
            'adp.Fill(ds, "tencmpC1")
            adp.Fill(ds)
            grid.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultView

            Dim dss As New DataSet
            'Dim dtt As New DataTable
            'adpp.Fill(dss)
            ds = dss.Tables(0)
            Dim count As Integer = ds.Rows.Count

            txt1.Text = count

Comment: ok sachu I try one code here also that is not working 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546153/how-to-count-rows-from-sql-db-table-in-vb-net-wpf-application

Comment: @SoniaRehamn do you have a connection to sqlserver?

Comment: I am waiting for you sachu will u post answer for me?

Comment: yes sachu every thing I have

Comment: @SoniaRehman..Try the below code..its just a sample..you need to modify accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a sample ..just check and try your own way.

Sample:

```
Dim connetionString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim command As SqlCommand
Dim sql As String
connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
                   User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
 sql = "Select count(*) from table"
 connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
 Try
   connection.Open()
   command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
   Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
   While sqlReader.Read()
   MsgBox("Count =" & sqlReader.Item(0))
   End While
   sqlReader.Close()
   command.Dispose()
   connection.Close()
  Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
 End Try
```

If your query return more than one values you can use `SqlDataReader()`, but if you are sure your query will return only a single value you can use `ExecuteScalar()` and if your query wont return any result, eg:- insert.it will insert value not return any data so we can use `ExecuteNonQuery()`.The ExecuteNonQuery() will return a result which indicate is it successful or failure. If you want you can assign the same else no need.

Comment: you can use anything depends on your requirement..since its return count and its a single value you can use executescalar as I specified..i just gave a guideline how to do..thats it

Comment: @SoniaRehman if u think mine is wrong you can downvote no issue..i just asked the reason

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) method to execute query that return singular/scalar value (example based on that link) :

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim connString = "connection string to your database here"
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable", conn)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Using
```